# Sprout SEO - Not all pages have a canonical tag

Tags: plugin-sproutseo

I'm using Sprout SEO on my site, and for some reason not all pages have a canonical url tag. Many pages have a canonical tag (the home page has one, for example), but a large number of pages are missing the canonical tag (many of my blog post pages, as an example).

I may be missing something, but I can't figure out how to get Sprout SEO to output a canonical tag for all pages. I tried adding:

```
{% do craft.sproutSeo.meta({
  canonical:  craft.request.url 
}) %}
```

But this resulted in the same behavior - some pages had canonical tags while others didn't. I just need all my pages to output a canonical tag.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you drop us a note at Sprout Support with more information about how you have Sprout SEO setup? It would be helpful to see your full template as well as your db if possible: https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/request/support

Comment: I actually was able to figure out the issue on my own. I wasn't aware that the site used a different layout file for some pages (another dev built the site). Thank you so much for your response!